# Homework time! Find me the lowest even digit in a string

Tags: code-golf

[Another brilliant question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20696011/764357) turned into a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge!

Write a program that:

1. Accepts a **string** as user input (not *piped in* or a command line argument). The data type of the input must be a string, if the language does auto evals on input, it must be cast to a string.
2. Finds the index (0 or 1 based) of the first lowest even *digit*.
3. **Prints 2 integers**, the index and the lowest even *digit*.
4. If there is no even *digit*, return -1 as the index, the second number can be anything.
5. For the purposes of this *zero is not even*.

Test examples, given the string on the left output the values on the right:

```
25376  -->  0,2
523726 -->  1,2
583746 -->  4,4
53771  --> -1,0
_4___2 -->  5,2
```

**The winner: is the program with the lowest character count.** No bonuses, no penalties.

**edit: (about stdin)** I screwed up on the user input part, basically no piping data in, and no command line arguments. You must provide a user prompt of some kind within the program itself.

Comment: What if the lowest even integer has two digits? Ok, twas a joke.

Comment: @belisarius Grrr. very funny...

Comment: Given the sample input they gave, I had assumed they meant digit. Too late, challenge has been thrown down!

Comment: What's wrong with stdin?

Comment: How liberal can we be with the output? Must it be "1,2"? or would "(1,'2')" be acceptable?

Comment: @MtnViewMark I assume `(1,2)` is acceptable because Lego Stormtroopr's answer does exactly that (usually `[(1,2)]`)

Comment: @JanDvorak Because arbitrary rules, thats why.

Comment: @MtnViewMark Any data structure that spits out 2 numbers is ok.

Comment: Do you really need to link to a question that was removed?

Comment: Unclear on this: "as user input ... not stdin"  How are you defining the difference between "user input" and "stdin"? User input is most often, in a console app, read from stdin. Taking a look below, your Python reference example reads from stdin. It's late. Maybe I'm not seeing the obvious difference.

Comment: +1 for the link to the awesome question on StackOverflow.

Comment: "If there is no even digit ... the second number can be anything" - can the second number be *nothing*?

Comment: Also, do you care about non-terminating error output? I've got a script written, but it needs 41 characters to shut up the error output.

Comment: Why the limitation of zero not being even? That seems rather odd.

Comment: @lszi Because it means you have to work around the limitation of `0%2 == 0`. And no as long as it prints the numbers thats ok.

Comment: @DarrenStone That was me trying to be specific about input, and I think I got it wrong. Basically, you need to use an "input" call of some type, data can't be piped into the program or read as a command line argument.

Comment: Your input requirements really make no sense: For most systems, input comes from stdin, whether prompted by the program or no. Whether or not the input is piped in or not is not under control of the program. -- If your aim was to have users create an interactive program, then you should have been precise about the input and output (including formatting), and the interaction required.

Comment: @MtnViewMark For some interpreted languages, the method of input is not only controllable - it *must* be specified. In PowerShell, you can only take input as one of: argument ($args), pipeline ($input), or interactively (read-host). You *can* make a script that will take any or all of the above, but it requires a significant amount of extra work to do so.

Comment: @Iszi: "Why the limitation of zero not being even? That seems rather odd." Pun intended or not?

Comment: @Iszi +1 for nice pun (*That seems rather odd.*)

Answer (score 6):

## Golfscript, 26 (28) characters

```
'#{gets}'.'246'&8+$1<.@\?
```

Example:

```
;'583746'
.'246'&8+$1<.@\?
#44

;'53771'
.'246'&8+$1<.@\?
#8-1
```

live test: http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=Oyc1Mzc3MScKLicyNDYnJjgrJDE8LjA9QD8%3D

Explanation:

- `'#{gets}'` is an escape to ruby to satisfy the I/O requirements; STDIN is assumed to be empty
- `.` clones the input
- `'246'&8+` finds which even digits are present in the input, except `8` is always retained
- `$1<` sorts the list, then takes the first digit, but keeps it as a string
- `.@\?` orders the stack {digit, input, digit}, then finds the digit in the input; thanks @peterTaylor for noticing me of the [array, array] signature of `?`.

I've been very bold with the spec interpretation this time; namely:

- The spec does not mandate in which order the integers are output; Use the other @peter's suggestion `:x?x` to fix (I don't like temporary variables.
- The spec does not require any delimiter between the two integers; since the digit found is always a single digit, this does not matter much. If it does, append `n@` (which also performs the swap), `n\` (which doesn't), or `` ]` `` (which formats the output as `["8" -1]`).

Comment: They aren't crazy requirements, they are arbitrary requirements :P

Comment: Also, the spec requires the index to be first, but I can't read GolfScript well enough to tell if you didn't

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr the only point of the spec that mentions the order is #4: "If there is no even digit, return -1 as the index, the second number can be anything". #3 does not specify the order; what about the "no delimiter" boldness?

Comment: Oh snap, you are correct sir! I mentioned the two numbers to output, but not the order. I stand corrected!

Comment: You can replace `.0=@?` with `.@\?` or `:x?x` to save one character and avoid the doubt over the order. Nice use of `8` as a fallback.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your input code doesn't (and can't be made to) work, because 1) the string needs to be *double*-quoted for Ruby escapes to work, and 2) even if you fix that, plain `gets` reads from the same default handle that has already been slurped dry by the interpreter. Also, even if you fix both of those, the Ruby code is normally executed at compile time, so you can't e.g. print a prompt before it. However, using `'"#{STDIN.gets}"'~` and running the program as `ruby golfscript.rb lowest_digit.gs /dev/null` *does* work, in the sense that you can print a prompt before, it if you want.

Comment: (Even that alone doesn't work in a loop to read multiple numbers, since GolfScript caches the values of strings. If you really want to do true interactive input in GolfScript, you need something crazy like `10,{'"#{STDIN.gets'\n*+'}"'+~}%` to read 10 lines of input.)

Answer (score 5):

### APL (37)

(1-based by default, but obeys `⎕IO`)

```
{×⍴m←⍵/⍨⍵∊'2468':z,⍨⍵⍳⍕z←⌊/⍎¨m⋄¯1,0}⍞
```

Explanation:

- `⍞`: read user input
- `m←⍵/⍨⍵∊'2468'`: remove all the characters that aren't `2468`, store in `m`.
- `×⍴m`: see if there are any
- `:`: If so:

  - `z←⌊/⍎¨m`: evaluate each character in `m`, find the lowest number and store in `z`.
  - `z,⍨⍵⍳⍕z`: return the index of `z` in `⍵`, followed by `z`.
- `⋄`: If not:

  - `¯1,0`: return `(-1, 0)`

Comment: Wow, I've beat APL (not with the J solution, but still...)

Comment: Explanation? APL is so self-explaining... ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Python 3 ,69**

combining ideas from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16083/homework-time-find-me-the-lowest-even-digit-in-a-string/16084#16084).

```
s=input();print(([(s.find(x),x)for x in'2468'if x in s]+[(-1,0)])[0])
```

Comment: I like the use of a string rather than a list, and the resulting omission of the (now removed) ` quotes.

Comment: @boothby I guess you didn't notice i'm using python 3. In python 3 [input()](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) Accepts a string as user input.

Comment: @SimonT  ` (backticks) are not just quotes. It is a deprecated alias for [repr()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) in python 2. But its no longer available in Python 3. So, If I wanna use `` on something in python 3, i have to write repr(something) which cost 4 more chars. Thats why i get rid of it ;)

Comment: @Wasi yes indeed, my mistake.

Comment: @Wasi, yes thank you.  I was aware of that and by "now removed" I actually meant removed as a part of the language altogether.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 60 characters

```
x=gets.chars.sort.find{|c|c=~/[2468]/};p x ?$_.index(x):-1,x
```

- `$_` contains the last input read by `gets`.
- `p` calls `inspect` on the arguments and prints the results.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6, <s>37</s> <s>55</s> *60* characters

```
$_=get;say m/<{~.comb(/<[2468]>/).min}>/.from//-1,',',$/.Int
```

EDIT: I misunderstood the question the first time. This update should be correct. It finds the lowest number of 2,4,6, or 8 that the input contains, and then does a regex match against the input with that lowest number. `$/.from` gets the position of the match and `',', $/.Int` is a comma plus the match itself, or 0 if the text didn't match.

While you're here, go upvote [G. Cito](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25952/15012), who helped me fix my entry in the comments and on irc :)

Comment: Unfortunately this prints first even number (2468) found and not the lowest :(  NB. Also there is an issue with `$/.from` when nothing is found (this maybe a bug in my old version of Rakudo).  Here's a variation of your solution which works (for me!) `my$x=get;for 2,4,6,8 ->$n{if $x~~/$n/ {say $/.from,",$/";exit}};say "-1 0";`  Comes in at 75 chars but I'm sure a shorter perl6 solution can be made.

Comment: @draegtun ... I made a similar error with my perl5 attempt yesterday (see below). My fix added 70 chars!  Just updated it with a ~50 char version - which seems to work. I think if you sort all the even digits in the number you can then do a match using the (now) first digit in the sort and be sure you have the lowest and the first.  Am I right?

Comment: @G.Cito Looks good to me and have already +1 your answer.  I can see way to shave off a few chars but I see Heiko as done even better than what I was going to suggest!

Comment: @draegtun Oh, geez, I completely misunderstood the question then :( Thank you so much! I'll update this ASAP

Comment: @mouq Here's an approach one that uses the same approach as the perl5 example I posted below: `my $n; $_="333992";$n=.comb(/<[2468]>/).min;/$n/;say $/.from//-1,",$/"`.  I learned about `.comb` about 20 minutes ago and I already like it :-)

Comment: @G.Cito Thanks for your help! Updated

Comment: I knew there must be a much better way than my suggestion! +1    However you need to show a second number (can be any number) when there isn't a match.  Here's one slight change that works but I'm sure it can be improved on: `$_=get;say m/<{~.comb(/<[2468]>/).min}>/.from//-1,",",$/.Int;`

Comment: Aww, okay -- thank you @draegtun! I'll update accordingly :)

Answer (score 3):

### perl - -<s>94</s>- 53 chars (or 48)

Instead of `index()`'s  zero-based approach we use `pos` and start at one; no CPAN. Run this with `perl -nE` and it will wait for input (which it can also receive from `STDIN`).

The first match (`//`) operation works on the default value (`$_`) from input, matching against the given even numbers, `sort`ing the matches into an array, and then storing them in a "scalar list" `($m)`. In scalar context the list value of the sorted array is one item long and thus consists of the lowest matched even digit in the number.

Having isolated the lowest even matched digit, we then use `$m` for a second match operation which will find the first occurrence of the value of `$m` in the original string. We are still using the default value here `$_` and we are saving the match against the contents of `$m` in `$1` (the reason for the `()` around `$m` in the second statement). After that, `pos` and `say` do the rest (and in fewer characters than `index` and `print`).

```
perl -nE'($m)=sort/[2468]/g;/($m)/g;$1?say pos.",$1":say"-1,0"'
33467
3,4
```

If output order or commas don't matter then it's possible to make this 5 chars shorter:

```
($m)=sort/[2468]/g;/($m)/g;$1?say$1.pos:say"-10"
```

In my earlier attempt I rushed and made an error - I just wanted to beat python and ruby (but failed) ... sigh.

Congrats to the winner and the other participants on their cool solutions - especially to `perl6` :-) A possible Perl6 adaptation of this approach could use "`.comb` (suggested on freenode by Masak *et.al.*).

```
$_=get;my $n=.comb(/<[2468]>/).min;/$n/;say $/.from//-1,",$/"
```

Comment: Was so focused on beating python/ruby that I posted a one liner that did not work when no even numbers were present: eagerly using an earlier version of the above from my `$SHELL` history for the "win". This working version is ridiculously long and embarrassing.  Serves me right: will shorten later to avoid shame :-(

Comment: older hack: `if(/[2468]/){for$i(2,4,6,8){if(index($_,$i)>-1){say$i,",",index($_,$i)+1;last}}}else{say"0,-1"}`

Comment: Good, but room is left for further golfing: `($m)=sort/[2468]/g;/$m/g;say$&?pos.",$&":"-1,0"` (47+1 bytes, AFAIK `-n` costs an additional byte).

Comment: NB. [`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html) returns the offset.  So in effect it's returning 1-based index in your example.

Comment: @draegtun oopsie :-) thanks.  @Heiko true that: switches should count otherwise `perl`'s `-M` would win every time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7 - 76

A reference answer I fully expect to be beaten. But to start people off:

```
s=raw_input()
print[(s.index(`e`),e)for e in[2,4,6,8]if`e`in s][:1]or(-1,0)
```

Comment: you can shave off a character by changing `index` to `find`; you can also change `[2,4,6,8]` to `2,4,6,8` (with space in front).

Comment: Shorter: `print[(s.find(\`e\`),e)for e in 2,4,6,8if\`e\`in s+'8'][0]`

Comment: I think you broke your own rule... Since when is raw_input not stdin?

Comment: `print[(s.index(c),c)for c in'2468'if c in s][0]or(-1,0)`

Answer (score 2):

## J, 44 characters

```
echo(;{&i){._1,~(#~(#i)&>)'2468'i.~i=.1!:1]1
```

outputs the last character of the input if no even digit is found

Example:

```
   echo(;{&i){._1,~(#~(#i)&>)'2468'i.~i=.1!:1]1
523726
+-+-+
|1|2|
+-+-+
   echo(;{&i){._1,~(#~(#i)&>)'2468'i.~i=.1!:1]1
53771
+--+-+
|_1|1|
+--+-+
```

Explanation:

- `echo ... i=.1!:1]1` is input/output. Way longer than I want it to. Input is stashed away into `i` as well.
- `'2468'i.~` finds the first occurence of each even digit in the input, returning the input length if the digit cannot be found
- `(#~(#i)&>)` reads "select by the length of input being greater than this"; in other words, select those indices that point into the input. Way longer than I want it to.
- `_1,~` appends -1 to the back. Underscore is the J's way of representing negative values.
- `{.` selects the first element
- `(;{&i)` concatenates it with the input character at that position in two boxes; since we're concatenating a number with a character, non-boxing concatenation (`,`) won't do. If unboxed display is desired, the index needs to be formatted (`":`) first at a cost of two chars.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 104

```
y=as.integer(strsplit(scan(,""),"")[[1]]);z=which(!y%%2&y);a=z[which.min(y[z])];cat(a,"-1 0"[!sum(a)],y[a])
```

Examples (in R, the index starts at 1):

```
_4_502
6  2

_3_501
-1 0 

583746
5  4
```

Answer (score 2):

### Powershell, <s>76</s> <s>73</s> 71

```
$s=read-host;2,4,6,8|%{if($i=$s.indexof("$_")+1){"$i,$_";break}};"-1,0"
```

- `$s=read-host`        stores user input into `$s`
- `2,4,6,8|%{...}`    runs what's inside `{}` for digits 2,4,6,and 8
- `$i=$s.indexof("$_")+1`  sets `$i` to 1-based index of a digit in `$s` or `0` if the digit is not found
- `if( $i=... ){...}`     the condition will be true when `$i` is not `0`
- `"$i,$_";break`         outputs the index and the digit, and stops execution
- `"-1,0"`                otherwise outputs `-1,0`

Comment: This does not output the proper index. In PowerShell, as in the test cases given for the question, indexes start at zero.

Comment: Rule #2 says the index can be 0 or 1 based.

Comment: Oh. Didn't spot that. Either way, here's a zero-based variant that's only 5 characters longer. `$s=read-host;(2,4,6,8)|%{if(($i=$s.indexof("$_"))-gt-1){"$i,$_";break}};'-1,0'`

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the parenthesis around `2,4,6,8` are unnecessary.

Comment: Zero-based variant can be made 2 characters longer, if you change the if condition to: `if(1+($i=$s.indexof("$_")))`

Comment: I'm lost. Why does `break` avoid `"-1,0"`? It's not part of the loop.

Comment: `foreach-object` (not to be confused with `foreach`) is not a loop in Powershell.

Comment: When is a loop not a loop? When it's a cmdlet!

Answer (score 2):

## C++11, 173 (including two new-line chars)

Here's the compressed version:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 
int main(){std::string s;std::cin>>s;for(char c:"2468")for(char&k:s)if(k==c){std::cout<<(&k-&s[0])<<','<<c;return 0;}std::cout<<"-1,8";}
```

Here's the readable version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main() {
    std::string s; // auto s = ""s; (since C++14: -3 characters)
    std::cin >> s;
    for (char c : "2468")
        for (char& k : s)
            if (k == c) {
                std::cout << (&k - &s[0]) << ',' << c;
                return 0;
            }
    std::cout << "-1,8";
}
```

---

Here's an older version:

**C++11, 175 (including two new-line chars)**

Here's the compressed version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main(){std::string s;std::cin>>s;for(char c:"2468"){int i=s.find(c);if(i<s.size()){std::cout<<i<<','<<c;return 0;}}std::cout<<"-1,8";}
```

Here's the readable version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    for (char c : "2468") {
        int i = s.find(c);
        if (i < s.size()) {
            std::cout << i << ',' << c; 
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "-1,8";
}
```

Comment: Try `#define o std::cout<<`.  I think it trims your code by 1 character.

Comment: @user2509848, nope, it's actually 2 characters longer. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: `k==c?std::cout<<(...),throw 0:0;` - the conditional operator can replace `if`, when all you need are expressions. `throw` is an expression and also one character shorter than `return`.

Answer (score 1):

### C, 80 character

```
main(){char a[81],b=strcspn((gets(a),a),"2468");printf("%d,%c",a[b]?b:-1,a[b]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 124

I'm a bit late to the party

```
void Main(string[]a){var x=a[0].Where(w=>char.IsDigit(w));var y=x.Min();Console.Write(y%2==0?a[0].IndexOf(y)+","+y:"-1,0");}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 79 characters

```
s&d=filter((==d).snd)$zip[-1..]$'0':s
main=interact$show.head.("24680">>=).(&)
```

This runs a little fast and loose with the output formatting:

```
& echo 523726 | runhaskell 16083-LowEven.hs 
(1,'2')
& echo 583746 | runhaskell 16083-LowEven.hs 
(4,'4')
& echo 53771 | runhaskell 16083-LowEven.hs 
(-1,'0')
& echo _4___2 | runhaskell 16083-LowEven.hs 
(5,'2')
& echo 25376 | runhaskell 16083-LowEven.hs 
(0,'2')
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell: <strike>145</strike> 103

> **Changes from original**
>   Removed error quelch per [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16083/homework-time-find-me-the-lowest-even-digit-in-a-string#comment30614_16083) from asker.

**Code:**

```
"$([array]::IndexOf(($s=(read-host)-split''|?{$_}),($x=$s|?{$_%2-eq0}|?{$_-gt0}|sort|select -f 1))),$x"
```

**Walkthrough:**

`"`...`"` Everything within the quotes will be included in the output.

`$(`...`)` Everything between the parenthesis will be treated as a commands, and the output of that code will be included instead of the commands themselves.

`[array]::IndexOf(`...`)` This is used to get the index of an element with the array. Its first parameter is the array object to be searched. The second parameter is the object to be found. This only outputs the index of the first matching element. I tried simply using an `IndexOf` method directly against `$s` (e.g.: `$s.IndexOf($x)`, but this fails for some reason I've yet to figure out - it claims the method doesn't exist on that object.

`(`...`)` Expression within the parenthesis will be the first parameter for `IndexOf`.

`$s=` $s will be a variable to store the user input.

`(read-host)-split''` Gets user input, and splits it into an array of characters.`

`|?{$_}` Filters out extra empty array elements that are generated by `-split''`.

`,(`...`)` Expression within the parenthesis will be the second parameter for `IndexOf`.

`$x=` $s will be a variable to store the lowest even digit from the user input.

`$s|?{$_%2-eq0}` Pulls out the even numbers from $s.

`|?{$_-gt0}` Invalidates zero.

`|sort` Sorts the remaining objects, default order is ascending.

`|select -f 1` Picks the first object, which will by now be the lowest even digit.

`,$x` The above code will output the index of our lowest even digit. This adds a comma, and then outputs the digit itself.

**Notes:**

This is perhaps stretching rule #4 a little bit. If there is no even digit, the output will not include a second number.

Also, this will throw some non-terminating errors if the input includes non-numeric elements. The script will still run and give proper output, but you might want to set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `'SilentlyContinue'` before running it.

Comment: @DankoDurbić Now that you've soundly defeated me, would you mind helping me figure out why I couldn't use `$s.IndexOf` here? It was giving me an error saying the method didn't exist for that object, even though `$s|gm` said it did. It works on the system I'm on now, but not the one I was trying to do it on earlier today. Is it a version compatibility issue? Earlier system was PSv2, current is PSv4.

Comment: Your `$s` is `string[]`, and `$s.indexof` doesn't work because `...[System.String[]] doesn't contain a method named 'indexOf'`, which seems reasonable (I'm running PS 2.0). `$s|gm` returns members of `System.String`, not `System.String[]`. I'm not sure why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

**vb.net (108c)**

```
Sub Main()
t=ReadLine()                          '12c
For Each c In "2468"                  '20c  
i=t.IndexOf(c)                        '14c
If i>=0 Then Exit For                 '21c
Next                                  ' 4c
WriteLine("{0},{1}",i,If(i<0,0,t(i))) '37c
End Sub
```

Smells slightly cos it's exploiting VB's dynamic setting. **Option Explicit Off** and **Imports System.Console**.

Answer (score 0):

**VB.net (193c) using LINQ**

This one is primarily utilising a LINQ query.

```
Dim r = From d In "2468" Group Join q In ReadLine.Select(Function(c, p) New With {.c = c, .i = p})
                              On d Equals q.c Into g = Group
                                        Skip While g.Count = 0 ' 138c
WriteLine(If(r.Any,r(0).g(0).i&","&r(0).g(0).c,"-1,0"))        '  55c
```

Answer (score 0):

### Golf-Basic 84, 91 characters

```
:L1/L1_L2i`L1:fpart(L1,2)2_L1:SortA(L1)@cumSum(L1)=length(L1):Thend`-1#d`cumSum(L1):Endd`L1
```

- Make sure there's no `0` in the input (it's not even, who said it had to be odd?)
- Get input into L1 (List 1)
- Loop finding modulus of 2 for each value
- Sort L1 from smallest to highest
- Display the index (either -1 or the cumulative sum) and the smallest number

Answer (score 0):

### Bourne shell (sh), 88 chars

```
(echo 88;sed 's/./\n&/g')|nl -v-1|awk '{print $2,$1}'|sed '/^[^2468]/d'|sort -n|head -n1
```

I thought I'd do a string-processing thing for fun.  Technically it reads from stdin, but if you run it interactively it'll prompt the user for input since the keyboard is the default stdin stream.  Uses basic shell commands to split up the input on lines, number them (using the ill-known `nl` utility), filter out lines fitting the criteria, sort them and output the lowest-digit one.  Prints `88 -1` if no even digit was found.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ - 223 <del>221</del> Characters:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>using namespace std;
int main(){int s=9;int p=-1;string x;cout<<"Enter characters: ";cin>>x;for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){int n=x[i]-48;if(n%2==0&n<s){s=n;p=i;}}cout<<p<<", "<<s;return 0;}
```

Readable version:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int s = 9;
    int p= - 1;
    string x;

    cout << "Enter characters: ";
    cin >> x;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
        int n = x[i] - 48;

        if (n % 2 == 0 & n < s) {
            s = n;
            p = i;
        }
    }

    cout << p << ", " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

It is long, but not as bad as Java.

Comment: It's actually 221 + 2 (new line characters) otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: Oh.  Word only detected 221, I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript 93 characters

```
b=prompt();((r=b.match(/[2468]/g)||[-1]).sort(function(a,b){return a-b})[0])+","+b.indexOf(r)
```

Get all event numbers, sort the array and prints the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 157 characters

```
f = Row@{If[(x = Min@#) == Infinity, -1, Position[#, x][[1, 1]]],
      ",", x} &[IntegerDigits@ToExpression@StringReplace[#,
       {"0" -> "1", x_?DigitQ :> x, _ -> "1"}] /. _?OddQ -> Infinity] &

inputs = {"25376", "523726", "583746", "53771", "_4___2"}

f /@ inputs // Column
```

> 1,2
>
> 2,2
>
> 5,4
>
> -1,∞
>
> 6,2

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 84

```
julia> f(a)=(for i=2:2:8;(k=search(a,'0'+i))==0||return(k,i);end;(-1,0))
julia> f(readline(STDIN))
583746
(5,4)
julia> f(readline(STDIN))
_4___2
(6,2)
```

Julia really needs a shorter way to get input for golfing. I counted the definition of `f` and one call to `f`. One based indexing is why the answers are different from the examples.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 53 Characters

```
for(y=prompt(x=0);x<8&&(i=y.indexOf(x+=2))<0;);x+''+i
```

Reads input from prompt and outputs (to the console) the lowest even character then (without a delimiter) the first index of that character; if there are no non-zero even characters then it outputs `8-1`.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 110 Characters

```
i,f,r,c,m=9;main(){while(r=getchar()>31){c=r-48;i++;if(c>=0&&~c&1&&c<m)m=c,f=i;}printf("%i,%i",m>8?-1:f-1,m);}
```

ungolfed:

```
i,f,r,c,m=9;
main(){
  while(r=getchar()>31){
    c=r-48;
    i++;
    if(c>=0&&~c&1&&c<m) m=c,f=i;
  }
  printf("%i,%i",m>8?-1:f-1,m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 69

```
a=prompt(),b=[-1,9];for(i in a)if(+a[i]%2==0&&+a[i]<b[1])b=[+i,+a[i]]
```

Reads the value, iterates through each character, if the number representation mod 2 equals 0 and the number is less that what is already stored in `b`, replace the values in `b`

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol, 69

```
s: input for n 2 8 2[if f: find s n[print[index? f f/1]q]]print[-1 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 55

```
p gets.chars.sort*''=~/[2468]/?[$_.index($&),$&]:[-1,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript/jQuery 149

Golfed

```
$(function(){
var i=prompt(),k=-1,n=0,c,e="2468";
while(n<i.length){c=i.charAt(n);k=e.indexOf(c);if(k>=0){break;}n++;}$('#d').append(k+","+n);
});
```

Full source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var i=prompt();
var k=-1;
var n=0;
var c;
var e="2468";
while(n<i.length){
c=i.charAt(n);
k=e.indexOf(c);
if(k>=0){
break;
}
n++;
}
$('#d').append(k+","+n);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```